# JavaScript - How display text from an array into a div with a 2 second delay

Tags: javascript, html

Still pretty new to this so forgive me something is not correct. I have an array with different strings of text, and I want to list each string in an html div with a 2 second delay between each line of text. I figured out how to display the whole array to the div element in html. However, I am having trouble trying to wrapping my head around how to add the 2 second delay affect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JS file -

```
var arrText = [
  "display after 2 seconds", "display after 4 seconds", "display after 6 seconds", "display after 8 seconds",
];
var html='';
for (var i=1; i < arrText.length; i++) {
    html+='<div>'+arrText[i]+'</div>';
}
document.getElementById('text-list').innerHTML+= html;
```

html file-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>delay test</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div>
       <div id="text-list" class="home-div"></div>
     </div>
    <script src="textScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty forward. After you create your string array.

```
var arrText = ["display after 2 seconds", "display after 4 seconds", "display after 6 seconds", "display after 8 seconds"];
```

Use `setInterval` function to execute the code every `2000ms`.
(Check console for results)

```
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (i < arrText.length) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = arrText[i];
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    console.log(div)
    i++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 2000);
```

Now, whatever gets inserted to your string array will be printed out after 2 seconds wrapped in an html `<div>` blocks.